# django column does not exist but no models.py and no changes found

Tags: python, sql, django

I am completely new to django, but I am trying to change a database table. I read a good amount of post about running

`python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate`

But when I run these two command, it does not detect any changes. A solution has been to change the models.py but I do not have that file. (I jumped aboard a working project, which appears to only have initialize the database once at the very beginning. I want to add a column to my .sql file which is copied from an .csv

`CREATE TABLE test (
columns
...
organ_system text <-adding only this line
...
more columns);
/COPY test FROM 'test.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;`

I have no clue on where to start/go.
The **init**.py file is completely empty if that means anything.

Answer (score 1):

it's normal for the `__init__.py` file to be empty. if you're missing a `models.py` file though something is a bit iffy as that is what django uses to talk to the database

you are correct that in order to make changes to the database you would have to modify `models.py`

Comment: So would it best just to make the models.py file?

Comment: Yes, if there are other apps in the django project you can go by

Comment: It is the only app with 3 database in the .sql file